# Cortex-M0+ setting the priority of the system exception

Tags: exception, arm

I am using Cortex-M0+ NXP LPC11U68 and I have an understanding problem. There is a [table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/BABICDEB.html) on the ARM website  which specifies that exceptions Reset, NMI and HardFault have fixed priorities from -3 to -1. All other exceptions (system and non-system) have configurable priority level.

As I understand these other exceptions has the priority 0 (the highest) if nothing is defined differently by the software. Am I right? Here I hit the wall. In the LPC11U68 manual (NVIC chapter) are registers (Interrupt Priority Register X) to define the priorities, but only for the peripheral units. How can I specify the priority level (from 0 to 3) for system interrupts such as SysTick Timer, SVCall or PendSV? The ARM site states "Configurable priorities for all exceptions except Reset, NMI, and HardFault." I am really confused how the priorities of system exceptions can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given any information about the development environment you use. But assuming you use some C code, you set the priority with `NVIC_SetPriority`, e.g.:

```
NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0);
```

BTW: -3 is of higher priority than 0 but only avalialbe for hard faults.

Also see: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__NVIC__gr.html

**Update**

I don't understand why you're so eager to use registers directly. `NVIC_SetPriority` is low-level. Anyhow, this is the [source code](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/core_cm0plus.h) (Cortex M0+ / CMSIS):

```
__STATIC_INLINE void NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t priority)
{
  if ((int32_t)(IRQn) < 0)
  {
    SCB->SHP[_SHP_IDX(IRQn)] = ((uint32_t)(SCB->SHP[_SHP_IDX(IRQn)] & ~(0xFFUL << _BIT_SHIFT(IRQn))) |
       (((priority << (8U - __NVIC_PRIO_BITS)) & (uint32_t)0xFFUL) << _BIT_SHIFT(IRQn)));
  }
  else
  {
    NVIC->IP[_IP_IDX(IRQn)]  = ((uint32_t)(NVIC->IP[_IP_IDX(IRQn)]  & ~(0xFFUL << _BIT_SHIFT(IRQn))) |
       (((priority << (8U - __NVIC_PRIO_BITS)) & (uint32_t)0xFFUL) << _BIT_SHIFT(IRQn)));
  }
}
```

Using this code, you can do it even more low level.

Comment: It's clear to me that -3 is higher priority then 0, but in the ARM specifies that it is possible to set the priority for SysTick (as an example). I need to know why there is no register in the NVIC to allow setting the priority of the SysTick. Only registers for peripheral units are available. I try to write the code on the lowest C level, so I am setting the registers.

Comment: I see you found the answer, but to make it explicit here: Priority of SysTick and PendSV exceptions are controlled via the SHPR3 register [B3.2.10 System Handler Priority Register 3, SHPR3] (and SVCall via the SHPR2 register).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all information! Now it is clear to me. I used "reverse engineering" from NVIC_SetPriority function to figure out that System Control Block (SCB) registers are not introduced in LPC11U68 manual. That is why I was missing something. Further information is found

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/CIHFDJCA.html

and

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/CIAGECDD.htm

p.s. I like doing with registers to get the lowest knowledge. I am using iSystem WinIdea development environment and not Keil uVision (ok, it was used for reverse engineering). Thank you once again!

Comment: There is certainly nothing wrong with understanding exactly how the system registers work, but the CMSIS NVIC functions are there for a purpose. The person who follows behind you (and it could be you yourself) will appreciate seeing a standard, well documented function to perform IRQ priority operations.

Comment: The reason the SCB isn't described in the LPC manual is it's part of the processor, bought as IP from ARM, and described in manuals by ARM, such as the Technical Reference Manual, and Architecture Reference Manual. The LPC documentation is about the peripherals connected to the ARM but created by NXP.